# Semisimple Lie subalgebra closed under JC decomposion

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I have a question about the tagged argument in [Prop. 8.5.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zvGg.png):
Let $g$ be a semisimple Lie subalgebra
of $gl(V )$.

For any $x \in g$ we have J-C decomposion $ x= x_s +x_n$ but that's not clear to me why $ x_s ,x_n  \in n_{gl(V)}(g) $ where $  n_{gl(V)}(g) = \{y \in gl(V) | [y,x] \in g $ for every $ x \in g \} $.

By the way: it would be enough to prove $ad(x_s)(g) ⊆ g, ad(x_n)(g) ⊆ g$, but I don't now how...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no answer, but what book is that?

Comment: Hi. That's from an online script. Here is the link to the whole pdf document: relaunch.hcm.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/perrin/chap8.pdf

Comment: Interesting. Thanks

Comment: If you still stuck on that question you can take a look at the book  Introduction to Lie algebras and Representation Theory" of Humphreys (page 29) he exaplains this there.